# How do I parse the values like this with BeutifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-re

I am trying to parse some information from awebsite but ran in to a little problem, the information I need wont print out and just shows `[]` when I need the values (3 for example from the source code provided. I would need some help to get it working. Hope someone here can help me out and assist in the matter.
Best of regards.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url_to_parse = "https://www.webpage.com"
response = requests.get(url_to_parse)
response_text = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, 'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify())
ragex = re.compile('c76a6')
content_lis = soup.find_all('button', attrs={'class': ragex})
print(content_lis)

source: <button class="c76a6" type="button" data-test-name="valueButton"><span class="_5a5c0" data-test-name="value">3</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

because the `find_all` returns in array to get item require to index on it or loop through the matches and that takes time if you know that the target is unique so you have to use `find` get the first match so in that case you should add attribute called `text` to get the value only

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_to_parse = "https://www.webpage.com"
response = requests.get(url_to_parse)
response_content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response_content, 'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())
regex = re.compile('c76a6')
content_list = soup.find('button',{'class': regex})
print(content_list.text)
```